# How to optimize index if expected result is limited to 50k?

Tags: index, mongodb, index-tuning

I have a collection where we are checking the recently active 50k users.

The collection has around 1m data.

And the query that we are using is this:

```
db.getCollection("UserLastActive").find({ }, { "_id" : 1 }).sort({ "Date" : -1 }).skip(0).limit(50000);
```

We already have an index on Date:-1 for descending sort.

However sometimes, the query is taking too long and incur a timeout. Is there any other way to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is, It will examine all 1m documents because you are not passing query to limit your result, the 50k limit is huge, try to reduce it to less, do partition by category, or any grouping properties.

Check the exact index use and execution state using [explain()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/).